# How can I remove the first characters in array values?

Tags: php, arrays, substr

I am creating an array, where I want to remove some characters:

```
  foreach ($Array as &$value) {
      $value = substr($value, 7);
  }
```

The output is:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "cat"
  1 => "frog"
  2 => "bird"
  3 => & "elephant"
]
```

How can I prevent, that the last character has an "&" sign?
Because when I later search for value via `in_array` then "elephant" is not found.

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: It's because you use `&$value` in your foreach - you need to use `unset($value);` after the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` sign indicates that there is still a reference to `$Array[3]`. To remove the reference use `unset`.

```php
foreach ($Array as &$value) {
  $value = substr($value, 7);
}

unset($value);

var_dump($Array);
```

The fact that "elephant" isn't found is likely caused by using `$value` later in the code, which changes `$Array[3]`.